# configure angularjs module to send patch request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am totally new to AngularJs. I am trying to send a PATCH request using Angularjs to Django Tastypie API's. My code is

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);

module.config(function ($httpProvider) {
});

function MyController($scope,$http)
{
$scope.patchCall=function(){
    $http({
    url: "/patchrequest/",
    data:data,
    method: "PATCH",
})
.success(function(data){
    console.log("SUCCESS");
    $scope.list = data.items;
}).error(function() {
    console.log("FAIL");
});
}
}
```

But when I am trying to send a request using this code I am Getting an error that  http.patch is not a function. Tell me how can i configure ng-app and services to send a PATCH request using AngularJs. I read PATCH request is available in $resource so i tired it with $resource also. But find the same result. Please guide me how can i configure an app from scratch to send CRUD requests, specially PATCH request

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: how are you calling the request? Can't see how you would get error `http.patch is not a function`

Comment: I am using AngularJs 1.1.5- min.js. I am callding the request is on button click . here i sent a request using Http. but when now i m reading somewhere there written it will go using ngResource.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your error doesn't make sense based on the code you're showing, but a common issue with adding `PATCH` to AngularJS is that it doesn't have a default Content-Type header for that HTTP method (which is `application/json;charset=utf-8` for PUT, POST and DELETE).  Here's my configuration of the `$httpProvider` to add patch support:

```
module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thank you @Kevin Stone, Today is my first day with AngularJs. So I am totally new., Perhaps I am making some other mistake also.Let me make changes and then see

Comment: @Kevin Stone is usage == `$http.patch(path, data);` ?

Comment: `$http({method: 'PATCH', ...})`

Comment: @KevinStone The [relevant RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902#section-6) defines the Content-Type header for JSON Patch as being `application/json-patch+json`.

Comment: Thanks, that's news to me.  You'll have determine what `content-type` your backend is expecting for a `PATCH` call.