# Building one object with only one $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I'm building a fullrest app with $resources, I read about It but I didn't find any answer.

```
return $resource('/rings', {}, { 
            getRings: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true
            },
            patchRing: {
                method: 'PATCH',
                params: {
                    slug: '@slug'
                }
            }
}
```

Get Rings is doing ok, but How can I "patchRing"? I mean I want to PATCH for endpoint: /rings/:slug Is this possible? or Do I need another $resource for that (like next one)?

```
return $resource('/rings/:slug', { slug: '@slug'}, { [...]
```

EDIT: I don't want the "PATCH" like this /rings?slug=lorem just /rings/lorem

EDIT 2: My point is only the endpoint construction... because $resource is requesting to /rings?slug=lorem instead of build request like /rings/lorem

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20305615/584846

Comment: It is not duplicate, that question is not the same issue than this...

Comment: But you may still need to include `'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'` in the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your config

```
$resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = true;
```

This will not end as /

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the param in the `$resource` definition instead of the PATCH method:

```
var Ring = $resource('/rings/:slug', {slug: '@slug'}, {
        getRings: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
        },
        patchRing: {
            method: 'PATCH',
        }
});

ring = Ring.patch({slug: 'lorem'}, function() { ... });
```

If the `slug` parameter is not passed, then it is not added to the HTTP path.

Comment: In this case if I not pass "slug", endpoint will be "/rings/" that is not what I want... I think this is not possible to do... ;(

Comment: The documentation for the `url` parameter says "If the parameter before the suffix is empty, :resource_id in this case, then the /. will be collapsed down to a single .. If you need this sequence to appear and not collapse then you can escape it with /\.."  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource