# Angularjs PATCH - undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use angular $http.patch() function to call a API URl
As recommended by these answers - [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000176/patch-request-using-angularjs) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305615/configure-angularjs-module-to-send-patch-request) i have set Content-Type headers to application/json in the config.

But still i get the error:

> undefined is not a function

I am missing here something? Below is my code where the error is throwing up (Note: I have injected $http in my service and other methods GET,POST,PUT,DELETE are working fine):

```
deleteAll: function (data) { // custom service function
                url = $rootScope.config.api.stack.add_stack;                
                return $http.patch(url,angular.toJson(data)); // error thrown here in firebug
            }
```

AngularJs version: v1.2.16

Even i tried using the latest angularjs version but still its not woking

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no patch method in $http. Use [$http with config](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage)

```
$http({ method: 'PATCH', url: url, data: angular.toJson(data));
```

UPDATE: Lukas's answer below is more relevant for now.

Answer (score 9):

There is a Method now: [AngularJs Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#patch)