# Angular Function Does Not Update Database

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a pair of Angular functions that should change a value from false to true when the user clicks a button. The app tracks a user's favorite books; when a user creates a favorite, the default values for 'tracking' and 'finished' are set to false. When the user goes to update them to true using an ng-click, the new 'true' values are not patched to the database, and are logged in the console as still false. Any thoughts on what's missing from my functions?

```
$scope.trackFavorite = function(favorite) {
      var favoriteParams = {
        id: favorite.id,
        tracking: favorite.tracking,
        finished: favorite.finished
      };
      favorite.tracking = !favorite.tracking;
      $http.patch("/api/v1/favorites/"+favorite.id+".json", favoriteParams).success(function(response) {
        console.log("READING NOW");
        console.log(response);
      });
    };

    $scope.markFinished = function(favorite) {
      var favoriteParams2 = {
        id: favorite.id,
        finished: favorite.finished,
      };
      favorite.finished = !favorite.finished;
      console.log(favorite);
      $http.patch("/api/v1/favorites/"+favorite.id+".json", favoriteParams2).success(function(response){
        console.log("IS IT FINISHED");
        console.log(response);
      });
    };
```

Here's the ng-click snippets from the view, just in case:

```
<div>
 <button ng-class="{tracking: favorite.tracking}" ng-click="trackFavorite(favorite)">Reading Now</button>
</div>

<div>
 <button ng-class="{finished: favorite.finished}" ng-click="markFinished(favorite)">Finished</button>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should look to catch the error(s) coming back from your promise, which will give you context into why it's not correctly saving.

Answer (score 3):

There could be a chance that you miss some http configuration. As it has been noticed here: [patch request using angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000176/patch-request-using-angularjs).

It would also be a good idea to implement the error function in your controller and for example update the form according to the response, that you get back.

```
$scope.trackFavorite = function(favorite) {
      var favoriteParams = {
        id: favorite.id,
        tracking: favorite.tracking,
        finished: favorite.finished
      };

      $http.patch("/api/v1/favorites/"+favorite.id+".json", favoriteParams)
            .then(
               function(response) {
                  console.log("READING NOW");
                  console.log(response);
                  //update the UI according to the response
                  favorite.tracking = !favorite.tracking;
               },function(error){
                 //clean up when an error occurs
               });

    };
```